# std::move gives error for moving std::string to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

In the code below, `std::move` gives 2 errors like this and takes me to some file called `functional`:

```
    1. /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<Fctor(std::basic_string<char>)>'
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^

    2. /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<Fctor(std::basic_string<char>)>'
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
     ^
```

Now, replacing `std::move` with `std::ref` works fine. I'm using C++11 supported QT Creator to code. I am learning C++ multithreading from [here](https://youtu.be/f2nMqNj7vxE) and this same code works fine on that video.

```
    #include <utility>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class Fctor
    {
    public:
        void operator()(std::string& msg)
        {
            cout << "t1 says: " << msg << endl;
            msg = "Trust is the mother of deceit.";
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        string str = "Where there is no trust there is no love.";
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;

        Fctor fct;
        std::thread t1( fct, std::move(str)); // DOES NOT WORK
        //std::thread t1( fct, std::ref(str) );
        std::cout << t1.get_id() << endl;

        std::thread t2=std::move(t1);

        t2.join();
        cout << "from main: " << str << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not the `std::move` from your code, but the one which a thread uses to pass arguments to a handler (which in your case expects a non const lvalue). There are many duplicates of this questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your functor `(std::string& msg)` , your function gets an l-value-reference, and you pass it as an r-value-reference.

This is why using `std::ref` succeeds, while `std::move` fails, but why are you trying to move the string into the thread constructor if you want to read it from the main thread?

Also, your code presents undefined behavior; you write to `str` from `t1` while reading it from the main thread. This introduces a data race condition which has undefined behavior.

I think you need to decide on the exact behavior of the string manipulation. And don't forget to synchronize the data with locks.

Comment: "*and you pass it as a r-value-reference*", it's what `std::thread` does

Comment: @David Haim Thanks for the answer and the explanation. I'm quite a beginner in C++.

void operator()(std::string&& msg) -> Solved it. Code works.

Comment: @muglikar are you beginner to programing in general?

Comment: "*you code presents undefined-behavior as you write to str from t1 while reading it from the main thread*" the problem is not a race condition, but the fact that the string was already moved from

Comment: @DavidHaim Yes to some extent.